# Добавление Bloom (Glow) эффекта к шейдеру (Unity)

Tags: c#, ios, unity3d, шейдеры

Всем привет! Я делаю iOS приложение на движке Unity.

Я пытаюсь переписать мой шейдер так, чтобы материал, использующий его, давал Bloom (Glow) эффект (примерно также как и компонент Halo).

Пример того как это должно выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я искал в интернете но не нашёл ничего рабочего или годного для решение моей проблемы.

Код шейдера:

```
Shader "Unlit"
{ 
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Main Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1) 
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
        LOD 100 
        Cull off
        ZWrite on 
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Pass 
        { 
            Lighting Off
            SetTexture[_MainTex]
            {
                constantColor[_Color]
                Combine texture * constant, texture * constant 
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```